Seeking Guidance on Automating SSRS Report Deployment Using a DevOps CI/CD Pipeline
I'm a DevOps engineer with some experience in automating the deployment of Tableau workbooks via GitHub Actions and Python and Tableau API. My current setup involves:

Utilizing GitHub Actions with reusable workflows.
Using Python to manipulate XML and interact with the Tableau API for:

Converting workbooks into templates and saving their metadata in Git.
Reverting these templates back into fully-fledged workbooks, incorporating updated metadata based on the target environment (e.g., switching data sources and connections for production).



Current Pipeline Overview

A developer commits a Tableau report to Git on a UAT branch, triggering a workflow that:

Extracts all metadata (like data sources and connections),
Strips this metadata and stores it in Git,
Creates and saves a template in Git.


Upon a PR to staging, the workflow:

Identifies the correct template,
Reconstructs data sources and connections using a configuration map,
Integrates updated connections into the template, saving it as a new workbook,
Finally, it publishes the data sources and the workbook to the staging Tableau server.



Request for Community Assistance
I am now looking to replicate this CI/CD strategy for SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). Has anyone in the community implemented a similar automation setup for SSRS? If so, could you share insights or even snippets of code that could guide me in adapting my existing process to SSRS?
